# Facebook like GridView to display images android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a layout with Gridview by custom library  [Click here StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

But not achieved the result that I needed.

Th `GridView` should auto adjust its column and row depending upon the number of images (min 1 images & max 4 images )  [like here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15860823518/)

news_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.rb.nonstop.HomeActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_sender_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_news_sender_photo"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_category"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_news_sender_photo"                       
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:text="News"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"       
             />

        <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"              
                android:background="@color/border"               
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_news_sender_photo"   
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_category"
                android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="5dip" />

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_sender_name_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_news_sender_photo"   
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"                   
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:text="Karthik Kolanji, Mumbai"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"       
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_news_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_sender_photo">

         <com.rb.lined.edittext.LinedEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:background="@null"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:padding="10dip" 
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"        
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="top|left"              

               android:minLines="10"
               />
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_news_date"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_news_content"
       >
        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:text="NewsFirst MobileApp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"                 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:text="September 10,2014 4:20 PM"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"   
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"               
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_news_grid_photos"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_news_date"
       >
       <com.jake.quiltview.QuiltView
        android:id="@+id/quilt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dip"
        app:scrollOrientation="horizontal|vertical" >               
        </com.jake.quiltview.QuiltView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.rb.nonstop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <include android:id="@+id/rel_news_default"
         layout="@layout/news_default"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity{

    public QuiltView quiltView; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        quiltView = (QuiltView) findViewById(R.id.quilt);
        quiltView.setChildPadding(5);
        addTestQuilts(200);

    }


    public void addTestQuilts(int num){
        ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logo);
            else 
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logo1);
            images.add(image);
        }
        quiltView.addPatchImages(images);
    }

}
```

[image: Current output]

[image: Expected output]

Comment: you should look at the QuiltView in this case.. [here](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary)

Comment: very much thank you for the quick reply ... let me implement this ...

Comment: @ Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille ---> I .tried to implement the library ... Its shows  Error inflating class com.jake.quiltview.QuiltView .. I configured it correctly ..Spend whole day in resolving error ..nothing worked :(

Comment: check you build path, may be its nt able to get the library.. post the log error that you are getting.. and also check if you need an xlmns attribute also

Comment: @ Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille ---> I edited my post .Pls see this.

Comment: https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary/issues/1 , check this, add android support v7 library and i think it will work

Comment: It is already in gridlayout_v7-master\bin  library

Comment: try adding the jar to ur own project

Comment: I posted the output ..I am getting layout like this ..

Comment: if 3 images , then it should split into 3 as in sample images I posted  . If 1 image , then 1 split , If 2 image , then 2 split, If 4 image , then 4 split

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use RecyclerView with [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html).

There is a great tutorial on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).