# How to divide imageview inside linear layout to different equal parts android

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am using 4 different `LinearLayout` inside  4 different `RelativeLayout`

4 different LinearLayout contains `Imageview` ( 1 `imageview` , 2 `imageview` , 3 `imageview` or 4 `imageview`) depending on the number of images avalailable for the specifc layout .

I achieved 1`imageview` , 2`imageview` layout successfully but not able to get  3`imageview` or 4`imageview`

I posted the expected image [image]

I tried QuiltView library  [My Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567044/facebook-like-gridview-to-display-images-android)  .. Didn't achieved the expected layout.

Also tried StaggeredGridView ...Library showed many errors ...

Hence applied my custom logic to get the expected layout

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_news_grid_photos_3"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_news_grid_photos_2"
       >       

      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_1" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/b" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/b" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/> 
         <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_3" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/b" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>    

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why brother downvote ....any specific reason ..or just timepass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the `weight` and `LinearLayout` relationship firstly. The below code works for 3 ImageViews.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_news_grid_photos_3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_news_grid_photos_2" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">       

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_1" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/b" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">


            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_2" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/b" 
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/> 
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/img_grid_3_3" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/b" 
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>    

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:** `weightsum` is the sum of weights on the current `LinearLayout`. For example your `LinearLayout` has 2 childs and they weights 0.5, so your weightsum will be 1. If you do not set this parameter, it has a value of 1 as default.

Comment: can u explain me diff bwtn weightsum and weight ?